# order by a condition oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using ORACLE SQL Developer.

I am trying to order by last name. If I have matching last names then I want to order by first name.

here is my code:

```
....
order by case 
when student_lname= student_lname
then student_fname
else student_lname
end;
```

but it doesn't return the result I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use two keys in the `order by`:

```
order by student_lname, student_fname
```